# How to make a Changelog?

Tags: php, mysql, changelog

For a Web-Application with many `Database` related events I want to build a `Changelog`. That should log what users have done, so its a Userlog too.
The App is huge, has a complex role based user access system and there will be hundreds of different events (changes) that may occur.

This all should be `Database-Driven`, in `PHP` and needs at least a `View` to search the `Logs`.

But in short, I have totally no idea how to design that all and need some tips or inspirations, maybe what others have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this in the past and found basically 2 approaches: Model-based and Controller-based.

- **Model-based** within the model itself override the `save` and `update` methods (assuming an *ActiveRecord* pattern) to create a new entry in the `ChangeLog` table.
- **Controller-based** add the `ChangeLog` record creation logic to each controller that you want to track.

I prefer the **Controller-based** approach since you have more control over what's going on and when. Also, you have full access to the user session so it's easier to add tracking for auditing purposes.

Comment: OK, Controller-based sounds very good, checked!

Now how to handle the huge amount of Events, especially the Names of them. Is it a good practice to use ids through a foreign Table, or better write the Names in a varchar as is multiple times or use some kind of Constants.....?
Well, at this point I prefer to write the Change-Event-Names as is, because it is the easiest, even if it costs more space in Database and appears a bit clumsy at all.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. I'm inspired by a simple Error-Log and write all as is now. As simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have solved that much more easy as it appears with my first thoughts.
This should do it most times without a comment:

```
protected function log($comment = ''){
    $user = $this->user();
    ORM::factory('Changelog')->vaules(array(
        'user_id' => $user->pk(),
        'section_id' => $user->section->pk(),
        'username' => $user->username.'@'.$user->section->name,
        'time' => time(),
        'uri' => $this->uri($this->request->param(), $this->request->query()),
        'controller' => $this->request->controller(),
        'action' => $this->request->action(),
        'post' => serialize($this->request->post()),
        'comment' => $comment,
    ))->save();
}
```

A simple $this->log() and all is done.

Result: http://charterix.sourceforge.net/log.jpg